# SELECTing data from SQL-SERVER to be formatted in a certain way

Tags: sql-server, select, vb6

I have a SELECT statement that pulls data from SQL-SERVER 2008. In the table, it's saved as values 1, 2 or 3 based on the selection from a combo box for Male, Female, Transgender respectively. I load this information into a Flex grid, however, it gets loaded as wither 1, 2 or 3. I need it to convert it to string (Male, Female, etc). I had stored procedure for another flex grid, so I did a case statement. In this case, I have a select statement in VB6 application and I'm having a hard time figuring it out especially since I'm specifying which table the data is getting pulled from. Please see code below:

```
 g_strSQL = "SELECT  tblFamilyMember.FirstName, tblFamilyMember.MI,           tblFamilyMember.LastName, tblFamilyMember.DOB, tblFamilyMember.SSN,tblFamilyMember.Sex, tblFamilyMember.ID "
g_strSQL = g_strSQL & "FROM tblFamilyMember FULL OUTER JOIN tblTest_Clients ON tbltest_clients.MemLocator = tblFamilyMember.MemLocator "
g_strSQL = g_strSQL & "WHere tblTest_Clients.MemLocator = '" & Me.lblMemLocat.Caption & "' "
```

This code is no in SQL-SERVER but inside vb6 application. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can use a case in this scenario as well. what is the issue when you use case?

Comment: When I use NEW QUERY in SQL-SERVER i use " " for translating the value. In VB6 I was using ' ' otherwise I was getting an error.

Comment: *When I use NEW QUERY in SQL-SERVER i use " "* , single quotes '' are required in SQL Server as well like this `CASE tblFamilyMember.Sex WHEN 1 THEN 'Male' WHEN 2 THEN 'Female' WHEN 3 THEN 'Transgender' ELSE '' END`

Comment: Got it!CASE WHEN tblFamilymember.Sex = 1 Then 'Male' WHEN tblFamilymember.Sex =2 then 'FEMALE' END

Comment: I was forgetting the END!!! Thanks!

Comment: That code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.